How to avoid this wrong annotation for first X tick in Seaborn - CountPlot with Hue?

categorical_var = ['Complains', 'Charge Amount', 'Age Group', 'Tariff Plan', 'Status']
numerical_var = ['Call Failures', 'Subscription Length', 'Seconds of Use', 'Frequency of use', 
                 'Frequency of SMS', 'Distinct Called Numbers','Customer Value']

def bi_var_analysis(category,target_variables):

    fig, axes = plt.subplots(2, 3, figsize=(18, 10))
    axes = axes.flatten()
    
    for i, col in enumerate(target_variables):
        if col in categorical_var:
            countplot = sns.countplot(x=df[category], ax=axes[i], hue=df[col])
            axes[i].set_title(f'{col} based on {category}')

            total = len(df[category])
            for p in countplot.patches:
                percentage = '{:.1f}%'.format(100 * p.get_height() / total)
                x = p.get_x() + p.get_width() / 2
                y = p.get_height()
                axes[i].annotate(percentage, (x, y), ha='center', va='bottom')

        else:
            barplot = sns.barplot(x=df[category], y=df[col], ax=axes[i])
            axes[i].set_title(f'{category} vs Average {col}')
            axes[i].set_xlabel(category)
            axes[i].set_ylabel(col)

            for p in barplot.patches:
                        height = p.get_height()
                        axes[i].annotate(f'{height:.2f}', (p.get_x() + p.get_width() / 2, height), 
                                         ha='center', va='bottom')

    plt.tight_layout()
    plt.show()

It annotates the 1 point in X axis with a 0. How do I get rid of that. It only pops up for hue chart. The Categorical and Numerical Vars and features. I just used barplot for Numerical and countplot with hue for Categorical for reporting clarity.

The easiest solution is to put a test if y > 0: before axes[i].annotate(percentage, (x, y), ha='center', va='bottom').

Note that your code is missing reproducible test data (it could be tested e..g. with seaborn's mpg dataset), and that categorical_var is an unknown variable.
